# Same class names with openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

OS: Windows, Spyder 3.3.3, Python 3.7.2

I am facing and error such as:

`File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)`

`File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)`

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'typeface'`

I believe the reason is because I am using classes with same name. For example, for one hand I have:

`openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font`

for other hand I have:

`openpyxl.drawing.text.Font`

For the first one, the tagname is `font`. For the second one it is `latin`.

I am using the first one to defined a `NamedStyle`. At the same time, I am using the second one to define the type of font used for axis labels.

I will try to give an example.

Next code gives the aforementioned error:

```
from openpyxl.drawing.text import Font, ParagraphProperties, CharacterProperties
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Border, PatternFill, Side

# Defining font for axis label
fon = Font(typeface = "Arial")
cx = CharacterProperties(latin = fon, sz = 1400, b = True)
ax = ParagraphProperties(defRPr = cx)
```

Next code works well:

```
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Border, PatternFill, Side
from openpyxl.drawing.text import Font, ParagraphProperties, CharacterProperties

# Defining font for axis label
fon = Font(typeface = "Arial")
cx = CharacterProperties(latin = fon, sz = 1400, b = True)
ax = ParagraphProperties(defRPr = cx)
```

How can I proceed without getting this missunderstanding?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: I don't think Python is confused about which `Font` you are using. After you define `openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font as font` and `openpyxl.drawing.text.Font as latin`, I guess, there will be no problem. If it is about that, try to use something else for `font` tag like `sfont`. If it doesn't work, please share the exact error and related part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Blame OOXML for having different definitions for basically the same objects. But in both XML and Python the elements/classes are isolated using namespaces. It's annoying but as long as you pay attention the namespaces you should be fine.

The elements are not interchangeable: you cannot use `openpyxl.styles.font.Font` in openpyxl.drawing.text.CharacterProperties elements. Also `openpyxl.styles.font.Font` uses the attribute `family` for the typeface.

```
from openpyxl.drawing.text import Font
fon = Font(typeface = "Arial")
```

Comment: I am trying to make it work but still getting the same error. It does not make sense. It seems only thrive the last `Font` called so only their properties are the "current" ones...

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Totally agreed with you Charlie. But, have you tried the example codes I specified above?

Comment: You **overwrite** the `Font` class in your imports!